# How can I get the 1st of January and the 31st of December three years ago with VB.Net or C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

I need to automatically prefill two Datepickers in VB/Winforms in code that should have the 1st day of the year and the last day of the year as their values, but always 3 years ago.

So for 2022 it should be 2019/01/01 and 2019/12/31.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Just set the displaydate property before showing the form

Comment: @pm100  And next year? Setting it again or have the code do it automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 3, 1, 1)` will give you the first day and

`new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 3, 12, 31)` will give you the last day

These expressions give you the dates you need. The correct place to assign them to the date pickers is either in the form constructor (after `Initalize()`) or in the `Form.Load` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;


namespace ControlFlow
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = DateTime.Now.Year;
            data -= 3;
            var firstDate = new DateTime(data,1,1);
            var lastDate = new DateTime(data,12,31);
            Console.WriteLine("First Date: " + firstDate.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Last Date: " + lastDate.ToString());


        }
    }
}
```